# Bus error 10 when working with string array - C

Tags: c, arrays, string, bus

I have a program that takes the non-option arguments (from the command line) after an option argument (-r, -d etc.) and inserts each non-option argument into an array. The maximum number of non-option arguments that can be typed in is 25.

But the problem is that when I run the program is gives a 'Bus Error 10" error and I'm not sure why. I've looked at so many posts with similar problems but can't seem to fix mine.

The code is:

```
void loop_namelist(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
int index = 0;
--optind;

char *buff_namelist[25]; //the array that the arguments are stored in
*buff_namelist = malloc(25 * 25); //allocating some memory for the array

while (optind < argc) //loop until no arguments left
{

    strcpy(buff_namelist[index], argv[optind]); 

    ++index; //move to next index in array
}
}
```

When I run it like this:

```
./program -r arg1 arg2
```

I get a bus error.

Comment: Compile with `gcc -Wall -g source.c -o program` (or enable all warnings and debugging info in your compiler) and learn how to use a debugger (e.g. `gdb`). Also, tell us what operating system and compiler you are using.

Comment: You know you only allocated space for the *first* pointer in your pointer array right? So as soon as `index` is greater than 0 this is **undefined behavior**.

Comment: I'm using the gcc compiler and those arguments as you said but still nothing. I'm using MAC OS X.

Comment: Please **use a debugger**

Answer (score 1):

Added some comments ...

```
char *buff_namelist[25]; //the array that the arguments are stored in

//you don't need to allocate memory for array, but in this case you need to allocate
//memory for each element in array better to do that in for loop
*buff_namelist = malloc(25 * 25); //allocating some memory for the array

while (optind < argc) //loop until no arguments left
{
    //instead of this you should allocate and then copy; or use strdup
    strcpy(buff_namelist[index], argv[optind]); 

    ++index; //move to next index in array
}
```

---

the correct code would be:

```
char *buff_namelist[25]; //the array that the arguments are stored in

while (optind < argc && argc < 25) //loop until no arguments left
{

    buff_namelist[index]= strdup(argv[optind]); 

    ++index; //move to next index in array
    optind++; //or somehow update optind
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can't believe I didn't realize I wasn't incrementing optind, too.

Answer (score 0):

your code

```
 char *buff_namelist[25]; // array that the arguments are stored in
 *buff_namelist = malloc(25 * 25); //allocating memory for the array
```

is completely wrong. At least it should be

```
 char* buff_namelist[25];
 for (int i=0; i<25; i++) {
   char* p = malloc(100);
   if (!p) { perror("malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
    buff_name[i] = p;
 }
```

but even the above is probably wrong. Perhaps you want to use `strdup`.

And most importantly if the `argv` is the second argument to `main`  you can copy the pointers in it (don't need to copy the string contents) like `buf_name[i] = argv[optind+i];`